# Automatic node finding with hyphenated ID names

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

In my HTML, I use an element with an ID like `<my-element id="my-widget">`

Then, in the DevTools, I can inspect `<my-element>`, and then in the console:

```
$0 --> <my-element id="my-widget">
$0.id --> my-widget
this.$.my-widget --> Uncaught ReferenceError: widget is not defined
```

This also happens when I try to get attributes. If the attribute is `my-data="hello"`:

```
$0.my-data --> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.$.my-widget` is parsed as `this.$.my - widget` (the subtraction of `widget` from `this.$.my`).

`this.$` is a [JavaScript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties), whose properties can be accessed by dot notation or square-bracket notation. So, `this.$.foo` is the same as `this.$['foo']`. Therefore, you can do `this.$['my-widget']` to access `<my-element>`.

Attributes are handled a bit differently. They're [mapped between dash-case and camelCase](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#property-name-mapping). Assuming:

```
<my-element id="my-widget" my-data="foo">
```

...you'd access the attribute with:

```
this.$['my-widget'].myData
```

Comment: My hero - also love the Boston avatar (go sox)

Comment: @BobbyBattista Haha, no problem :)

Comment: Although, this.$["my-widget"] is returning undefined :( maybe my "this" isn't pointing to the right thing? I'm using the javascript console from index.html, and <my-element id="my-widget"> is nested a few elements deep. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the full context, including the template?

Comment: Also note that `this.$` refers to only to named elements in a custom element's local DOM and not deeply nested children. (not sure if you meant that you were trying to use `this.$` from `index.html`)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m6tCWq12
If I strip out the guts and imports, it's basically just this. A nested custom element has a property that I would like to hard code for testing - so I send the value in as an attribute when using the inner-element tag. Now from the javascript console I want to access that attribute/property - I have no idea whether to use document.getElementById("my-widget"), this.$["my-widget"], or this.$$("#my-widget") - it's all confusing to me. The ones with "this" aren't working.

Comment: Yeah, so let's say I'm one or two levels into the nested custom elements, which each have their own local DOM... how do I drill down (or up)? Like, from index.html (document root), is it this.child.child["my-widget"]? And if I was using javascript console from my-widget.html, would something from index work like this.parent.parent["root-widget"]?

Comment: *Re: `this.child.child["my-widget"]`*: Yes, that's close. You'd first need a ref to the "nearest available element" from wherever you're querying. Then, you can drill down with properties or via `$`. Ex from `index.html`: `document.querySelector('my-app').$['my-widget'].myData = 'hello world';`

Comment: *Re: `this.parent.parent["root-widget"]`*: You shouldn't "drill up" (not recommended but not impossible). Data is propagated upward via events, so any interested parent elements would have to listen to a specific event and examine the event detail for data if necessary.

Comment: So is there an equivalent from index.html using "this?" And is there a way to use this.$$()? https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom

Comment: I assume you want `this` in order to use `this.$` and `this.$$`. You simply need a reference to a Polymer element for that, so you could just use `document.querySelector`/`document.getElementById` to get a ref to a Polymer element in `index.html`, and then use the `$` or `$$` off that ref. Ex: `const x = document.querySelector('my-app').$$('.input-container');`.